# Merge html reports for different minitest classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have a bunch of separate classes which have Minitest::Test as a superclass.

To run all the tests, I am using next batch script:

```
for /r "." %%a in (SLA_*.rb) do ruby  "%%~fa" >>"%~f1results.log"  | type results.log
```

This basically means I run every class separately. I then receive final results merged in the results.log file.

Now, I also have the results in html reports, which are generated using Minitest::reporters:

```
  html_reporter = Minitest::Reporters::HtmlReporter.new(:output_filename => name+'.html')
  Minitest::Reporters.use! [Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new, html_reporter]
```

The problem is that all of those classes generate a different html report(if I use the default name instead of my custom output_name, the file will be overridden).

Is there any way to merge html reports instead of generating new ones?